# React setState at 60hz

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crash

This isn't my actual component I'm working with, but an example that demonstrates the issue I'm running into:

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);
  
  const onClick = () => {   
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
      onClick();
    }, 20)
  }

  return (
    <p>{counter}</p>
    <button onClick={onClick}/>
  );
}
```

Yes, I'm aware that this won't ever stop, in my actual code I have some mechanism for it to stop. The problem I'm running into though is chrome crashes and shows a black screen always after about 1000 increments. What's wrong with this code? I'm having the React component rerender at around 60hz, is that a problem?

Comment: The stuff I'm doing is pretty complicated and probably not worth describing, my point is I need the component to refresh at 60hz to render what I want to render, and running `setCounter` that quickly is crashing my browser.

Comment: Works for me with a proper effect/cleanup implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-robinson-s37vy2?file=/src/App.js. Tested on the latest chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run "onClick()" as a callback function, when your state has changed. First argument for setState hook is the new value for the state, the second argument is a callback function that you can provide.

```
    const onClick = () => {   
     setTimeout(() => {
      setCounter((counter => counter + 1),  () => {
          onClick();
      });
    }, 20)
  }
```

Edit:
Altough im pretty sure my above answer with a callback inside setCounter hook should work, here is another method:

Define a useEffect with counter as a dependency.

Import {useEffect} from „react“;

```
useEffect(() => {
onClick();
},[counter]);
```

That way, everytime your counter changes, onClick is run again.

Comment: by the way, setting a state is asynchronous and NOT instantly done! It can take different amounts of time until the new state is set. Keep that in mind.

Comment: This extra callback is not an argument to the setCounter function...

Comment: Oh am i mistaken? Hm im on the subway at the moment, so i cant try by myself. 
Try to use an useEffect with [counter] as a dependency array. Inside this useEffect, call onClick. Thats another way.

Comment: Please look at my edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually figured it out. It turns out that there's nothing wrong with refreshing the component at 60hz. What I didn't tell you is that I'm working with webworkers and I had a call `const worker = useRef(new Worker())` and I believe this was running on every refresh.